# acute triangle and internal point

Tags: geometry

In the acute triangle $ABC$ distances from internal point $S$ to sides $a,b,c$ are respectively $d_{a}, d_{b}, d_{c}$. Show that $\frac{d_{a}}{h_a}+\frac{d_b}{h_b}+\frac{d_c}{h_c}=1$ where $h_a, h_b, h_c$ are heights, such that $h_a$ starts on vertex $A$ and ends on side $a$, etc.

I thought to calculate it using areas, but I have problem with appliance it.

Comment: Consider the triangles $ABS$, $BCS$, and $CAS$.

Comment: thanks for hint, now I'am able to tackle this one

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $A$ denote the area of the triangle.  Then $2A=ad_a+bd_b+cd_c$.  OTOH $2A=ah_a$ thus $a= 2A/h_a$, similar for $b$ and $ c$.